# get the attributes for attribute set in magento

Tags: magento

how do I find the values of a product's attribute set?

For example,

1. shirts, i need to get all the active attributes like color,size and
   gender.
2. cellphones, i need to get all the active attributes like color(size
   attribute not exists for phones)

how do I find the values of a product's attribute set?

i am able to getting the attribute set value in the following way:

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); 
   $prodAttributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_set_api')->items($setId);
```

The class is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Api` it seems to have two methods. The `items()` methods seems to do what you ask i.e. "`Retrieve attributes from specified attribute set`"

Also you can refer

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-attribute-set-in-magento/

```
$attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($attributeSetId);
foreach($attributes as $_attribute){
    print_r($_attribute);
}
```

Good attribute set Documentation

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-attribute-set-in-magento/

hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to access the API class. There is a more natural approach available. If you have a product:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product **/
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
```

If not:

```
$attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
  ->loadAllAttributes()
  ->getSortedAttributes($attributeSetId);
```